# How to return the json in a required format

Tags: python

Json is below

```
result = {
  "took" : 21,
  "timed_out" : False,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 5,
    "successful" : 5,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 1.0,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "data",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "qwcs",
        "_score" : 1.0,
        "_source" : {
          "id" : "10",
          "name" : "Country ",
          "description" : "This product contains all currency details",
          "Owner" : {
            "id" : "11",
            "Name" : "David",
            "Email" : "nons@utc.com",
            "role" : "Analyst"
          },
          "Area" : [
            "Data Management"
          ],
          "Type" : [
            "API",
            "TXT"
          ],
          "Level" : [
            "A"
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

I wrote the python code to extract the data from elastic through api hit  and above is the result

- sample api: http://utc.com/search/Owner.id?=11
- Back-end query will generate `{'query': {'match': {'Owner.id': '11'}}}`
- But i need only small details the expected out is below

  ```
          "Owner" : {
            "id" : "11",
            "Name" : "David",
            "Email" : "nons@utc.com",
            "role" : "Analyst"
          }
  ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're saying you want to return only the `Owner`s in the `hits` list with an `id` matching your query, you can use a list comprehension:

```
query = {'query': {'match': {'Owner.id': '11'}}}
owners = [hit['_source']['Owner'] for hit in result['hits']['hits'] 
    if hit['_source']['Owner']['id'] == query['query']['match']['Owner.id']]

print(owners)
```

Output:

```
[{'id': '11', 'Name': 'David', 'Email': 'nons@utc.com', 'role': 'Analyst'}]
```